# I'm trying to solve the shortest path of Dijkstra algorithm. I know this is not right, but what should I do to make it work?

Tags: java, shortest-path, dijkstra

Calculates the edge-weighted shortest path from start to target
Uses a minimum distance heuristic from any vertex to the target
in order to reduce the number of visited vertices during the search

weightMapper provides a function, by which the weight of an edge can be retrieved or calculated
return the shortest path from start to target,
returns null if either start or target cannot be matched with a vertex in the graph
or no path can be found from start to target

```
public DGPath dijkstraShortestPath(String startId, String targetId,
                                       Function<E, Double> weightMapper) {
        V start = this.getVertexById(startId);
        V target = this.getVertexById(targetId);
        if (start == null || target == null) return null;

        // initialise the result path of the search
        DGPath path = new DGPath();
        path.start = start;
        path.visited.add(start);

        // easy target
        if (start == target) return path;

        // keep track of the DSP status of all visited nodes
        // you may choose a different approach of tracking progress of the algorith, if you wish
        Map<V, DSPNode> progressData = new HashMap<>();

        // initialise the progress of the start node
        DSPNode nextDspNode = new DSPNode(start);
        nextDspNode.weightSumTo = 0.0;
        nextDspNode.marked = true;
        progressData.put(start, nextDspNode);

        Map<V, E> visitedEdges = new HashMap<>(); // visitedEdges of a certain vertex
        visitedEdges.put(start, null); // we start with source as visited vertex without edge

        while (nextDspNode != null) {

            /*
             * continue Dijkstra's algorithm to process nextDspNode
             * mark nodes as you complete their processing
             * register all visited vertices while going for statistical purposes
             * if you hit the target: complete the path and bail out !!!
             */


            for (E edge : nextDspNode.vertex.getEdges()) {
                V neighbour = edge.getTo();
                DSPNode neighbourNode = new DSPNode(neighbour);
                double weight = weightMapper.apply(edge);
                double distanceFromNextNode = nextDspNode.weightSumTo + weight;
                if (distanceFromNextNode < neighbourNode.weightSumTo) {
                    neighbourNode.weightSumTo = distanceFromNextNode;
                    neighbourNode.fromEdge = edge;
                    neighbourNode.marked = true;
                    progressData.put(neighbour, neighbourNode);
                }

                /*
                 find the next nearest node that is not marked yet
                //  nextDspNode = progressData.values().stream()...
                 */
            }
            if (nextDspNode.vertex == target) break;
            nextDspNode = progressData.values().stream().filter(dspNode -> !dspNode.marked).reduce((o1, o2) -> {
                int compare = Double.compare(o1.weightSumTo, o2.weightSumTo);
                if (compare > 0) return o1;
                else if (compare < 0) return o2;
                else return o1;
            }).orElse(null);
        }

        path.totalWeight = progressData.values().stream().mapToDouble(value -> value.weightSumTo).sum();

        // no path found, graph was not connected ???
        return path;
    }
```

helper class to register the state of a vertex in dijkstra shortest path algorithm

```
// helper class to register the state of a vertex in dijkstra shortest path algorithm
private class DSPNode implements Comparable<DSPNode> {
    public V vertex;                // the graph vertex that is concerned with this DSPNode
    public E fromEdge = null;        // the edge from the predecessor's vertex to this node's vertex
    public boolean marked = false;  // indicates DSP processing has been marked complete
    public double weightSumTo = Double.MAX_VALUE;   // sum of weights of current shortest path to this node's vertex

    public DSPNode(V vertex) {
        this.vertex = vertex;
    }

    // comparable interface helps to find a node with the shortest current path, sofar
    @Override
    public int compareTo(DSPNode dspv) {
        return Double.compare(this.weightSumTo, dspv.weightSumTo);
    }
}
```

```
Here are the expected results

    @Test
    void checkDSPSearch() {
        DirectedGraph.DGPath path = europe.dijkstraShortestPath("UK", "LUX", b -> 2.0);
        assertNotNull(path);
        assertEquals(europe.getVertexById("UK"), path.getStart());
        assertEquals(4.0, path.getTotalWeight(), 0.0001);
        assertEquals(path.getTotalWeight(), 2.0 * path.getEdges().size(), 0.0001);
        assertTrue(path.getVisited().size() > path.getEdges().size());
    }
```

Comment: **_"it's not working"_** is not a good problem description. Please post  [mre]. Include hard - coded test data and the expected result.

Comment: I hope this makes it a bit more clear. I would really appreciate it if you can help me

Comment: I'll try after you do what is needed for me to help you. MRE means I should be able to copy-paste run.

Comment: Shall I join you on Gitlab ? Because the project that I'm wroking on is quite full of code

Comment: No. SO is a shared resource, not a private help service. You should not post a long. Instead prepare am mre or [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. But I have solved it by applying the A star algorithm

Comment: Consider deleting the question since it has no value for others.